# New NIC not seen by VMWare Esxi 5.1

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant

We have an HP DL380G7 Server thats been in production for 5 years running VMWare Esxi 5.1. I have just added a new NIC to the server to interface with a new HP MSA 2040 SAN.

I needed to add a secondary riser card to the server to fit this card in as there are already 3 NIC's in the server.

The new NIC is:
AJ764A  HP FIBRE CHANNEL HBA 8GB DUAL PORT 82Q

In vSphere, when I view Configuration > Network Adapters, I cannot see the new NIC listed.

I double checked the VMWare compatability guide (http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=io&productid=12687) and seems the card is supported and it directed me to the "qla2xxx version 901.k1.1-14vmw" driver.

I am unable to locate this driver, so instead I opted for the following VIB file: QLogic_bootbank_scsi-qla2xxx_934.5.45.0-1.vib

I have installed this VIB and rebooted the server and the NIC is still not seen.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you try searching HP's website? It might be worth downloading it from there and installing it, although it does look like you'll end up with the same version of the driver from what I can see.

Comment: Yes, I have also tried using the driver on the HP website and the card is not detected.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I didn't realise that this card is actually seen as a hard drive (storage adapter) and not a network adapter.